# How to remove entire sentence if it is containing string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I need to remove the entire sentence from the string if it is containing a pattern.
Here I have the pattern "Link" or "link", if it is present in the string, I need to remove the entire sentence containing it.

```
std::string subject = "This is previous sentence. This can be any sentences. Link 2.1.19.3 [Example]. This is can be any other sentence. This is next sentence.";   

std::string removeRedundantString(std::string subject)
{
    std::string removeSee = subject;
    std::smatch match;  

    std::regex redundantSee("(Link.*$)");

    if (std::regex_search(subject, match, redundantSee))
    {
        removeSee = std::regex_replace(subject, redundantSee, "");
    }
}
```

Expected Output :

```
This is previous sentence. This can be any sentences.This is can be any other sentence. This is next sentence.
```

Actual Output :

```
This is previous sentence. This can be any sentences.
```

The above actual output is coming because of regex used `"(Link.*$)"` which remove the sentences starting from Link to the end of the string.
I am not able to figure out what regex is used to get the expected output.
Here are the different test cases I need to test :

Testcase 1:

```
std::string subject = "Note this is second pattern, Ops that next the scheduler; link the amount for the full list of docs. The number of value varies from 0 to 4.";
```

Output: `Note this is second pattern, Ops that next the scheduler;The number of value varies from 0 to 4.`

Testcase 2:

```
std::string subject = "This is another pattern. (Link Doc::78::hello::Core::mount). Since this patern includes non-numeric value.";
```

Output : `This is another pattern.Since this patern includes non-numeric value.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your Testcase1, you seem to be counting `;` as the end of a sentence. How exactly are you defining a "sentence"?

Comment: Try `std::regex redundantSee(R"(\W*\b[Ll]ink\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*|[^.])*[.?!])")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks, it is working and passing all the test cases, it would be very helpful if you provide detail steps and logic implementation for your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend

```cpp
std::regex redundantSee(R"(\W*\b[Ll]ink\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*|[^.])*[.?!])")
```

See [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODGoXd/1). Note the raw string literal syntax, `R"(...)"`. The string pattern can be simply put inside instead of `...` without any additional escaping.

*Regex details*:

- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[Ll]ink` - `Link` or `link` word
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*|[^.])*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` - one or more digits followed with zero or more sequences of `.` and one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[^.]` - any char other than a `.`
- `[.?!]` - a `?`, `.` or `!`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, is good for you to keep in mind that the end of a string is not the next `.` character, it's the end of memory region that the variable `subject` refers to. So, when you match the end of the string, the regex engine will go to the end of that memory.

For instance, we can have `string str = ".......................";` and the end of the string will be the last `.` character.

What you are trying to do, I suppose, is match the word "link" until the next `.`. For this, you should define a charset (consisting of upper and lowercase letters, numbers, spaces, and colon characters, according to your testcases).

A regex resembling this one `link([0-9a-z ]*)\.` can be used.

Also, before you use those, I suggest you test your regexes in some places, like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).